# What types of animation does VTK support for poygonal meshes?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, vtk, medical-imaging

I've a bunch of expereince in 3D rendering from a game-dev perspective but very little with serious toolkits like VTK.

We have a 3D model of a medical device which has a couple of degrees of motion, and we need to visualise this, animated, in a medical application alongside DICOM datasets.

In a 3D engine we'd likely have option to keyframes, morph-targets, skeletal rigging... but I cannot find out what VTK supports (skeleton/bone are bad search terms as most uses are medical!)

Can someone enumerate what options are provided and point me where in the docs this is covered?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any concise "documentation of VTK animation methods" (doesn't mean there isn't one though), but I will at least share what I know. First off, I doubt that there is some really great state-of-the-art solution included in the base VTK, personally I would look for algorithms that are good enough for me (produce high quality animation) and then try to find an open source implementation of them rather than the other way around. Try including "non-rigid transformation / animation" in your search.

Anyway, two things I know of that are in VTK: there is a filter for Mean Value Coordinates morphing, https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDeformPointSet.html, which you can use for a cage-based deformation (which is perhaps not the most user friendly for creating animations) or in theory could be used for rigging as well (never tried that, but right now I can't see why it wouldn't work). Next, there is an Iterative Closest Point morphing filter https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkIterativeClosestPointTransform.html that you could use for morphing by key frames.

Comment: I had this task once and in the end we went with a commercial engine.